# c++ - conditional assignment of const, without ternary?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, constants, variable-assignment

suppose I want to assign a const variable based on complex calculations which depend on a conditional.

if the situation were simple, I could do:

```
const int N = myBool ? 1 : 2;
```

but it's more like

```
const int N = myBool ? <lengthy calculation> : <other lengthy calculation>;
```

What I'm doing is this, but I'd like something cleaner:

```
int N_nonconst;
if (myBool) {
  N_nonconst = <lengthy calculation>;
}
else {
  N_nonconst = <other lengthy calculation>;
}
const int N = N_nonconst;
```

obviously, I could also do this:

```
int possibility1 = <lengthy calculation>;
int possibility2 = <other lengthy calculation>;
const in N = myBool ? possibility1 : possibility2;
```

but I'd like to actually perform only one of those lengthy calculations.

If I were extending the language, I'd consider making something like a `const_deferredAssignment` declaration:

```
const_deferredAssignment int N;
if (myBool) {
  N = <...>;
}
else {
  N = <...>;
}
```

I could also wrap those calculations up in functions/methods, but they use a bunch of locals, so it would be a fairly verbose function call.

Comment: And what would be wrong with a "fairly verbose function call"?

Comment: Nothing technical, it's just more verbosity than I'm hoping for.

Comment: BTW, Swift lets you declare an uninitialized const var which is immediately set by if/else block. I wish C++ did this.

Comment: I'm now working in Swift, and I love the uninitialized const variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could wrap each calculation in a lambda, and capture the local variables to reduce the verbosity of their arguments

```
{
    // ...

    auto firstFunc = [&]() -> int { ... };
    auto secondFunc = [&]() -> int { ... };
    
    const int N = myBool ? firstFunc() : secondFunc();
}
```

In this way only one of the two functions are actually executed.

Comment: I like this, it has a certain elegance.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure if Lambda's are present in the flavor of C++ I'm working with, but I'll give them a try.   I wish I could select two answers, as yours and Sean's are so similar and came in at the same time.  I'm selecting yours.

Answer (score 6):

You could move the lengthy calculations to a separate function:

```
int lengthCalculation()
{
  if(myBool)
  {
    return <lengthy calculation>;
  }
  else
  {
    return <other lengthy calculation>;
  }
}

const int N = lengthCalculation();
```

If you don't want to create a separate function that you can use a local lambda:

```
const int N = [&]()
{
  if(myBool)
  {
    return <lengthy calculation>;
  }
  else
  {
    return <other lengthy calculation>;
   }
}();
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure if Lambda's are present in the flavor of C++ I'm working with, but I'll give them a try.   I wish I could select two answers, as yours and Cory's are so similar and came in at the same time.  I'm selecting Cory's.  You look like you're doing okay on reputation!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you could try and use

```
SWITCH(myBool) 
{

Case 0 : first_lengthy_calculation

         Break;

Case 1 : second_lengthy_calculation

         Break;

}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure how this solves the issue of assigning the result to a const.